How initialization delegate to class?
Good afternoon everyone.
Guys, tell me how it is possible to add a delegate to the Menu?
I have a class MenuMainView which uses a delegate.
protocol IChangeMenuItemHandler: AnyObject {
    func changeMenuItem() -> Void
}

I dont add delegate to initializatio. XCode is show error Property 'self.delegate' not initialized at super.init call
import UIKit

protocol IChangeMenuItemHandler: AnyObject {
    func changeMenuItem() -> Void
}

final class MenuMainView: UIView {

    // MARK: - Dependencies
    let fabricShadow = FabricShadows()

    // MARK: - Private properties
    private var menuItem: MenuItem!
    private let delegate: IMenuDelegate!
    private var handlerChangeMenuItemDelegate: IChangeMenuItemHandler?
    private let heightButton = GlobalSizes.Height.heighButton


    private lazy var gradient = createGradient()
    private lazy var viewDieShadow = createView()
    private lazy var viewDie = createView()
    private lazy var labelNameMenu = createLabel()
    private lazy var buttons: [UIButton] = []
    private lazy var vStack = createStack([])

    // MARK: - Initializator

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)  // This is error: Property 'self.delegate' not initialized at super.init call
        addUIView()
        setupConfiguration()
        setupLayout()
    }

    convenience init(
            frame: CGRect,
            menuItems: MenuItem.Type,
            delegate: IMenuDelegate,
            handlerChangeMenuItemDelegate: IChangeMenuItemHandler?
    ) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.handlerChangeMenuItemDelegate = handlerChangeMenuItemDelegate
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// MARK: - UI Action.
private extension MenuMainView {
    @objc func showMapsScene(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let item = MenuItem.allMenuItems[sender.tag]
        handlerChangeMenuItemDelegate?.changeMenuItem()
    }
}

How add delegate handlerChangeMenuItemDelegate to class Menu?
I am have error - Variable 'self.menuView' used before being initialized
final class Menu {
    private let delegate: IMenuDelegate
    private let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
    private(set) var menuView: MenuMainView
    var currentMenuItem: MenuItem = .maps
    var handlerChangeMenuItemDelegate: IChangeMenuItemHandler?

    internal init(delegate: any IMenuDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.menuView = MenuMainView(
            frame: screenSize,
            menuItems: MenuItem.self,
            delegate: delegate,
            handlerChangeMenuItemDelegate: self. // This is error: Variable 'self.menuView' used before being initialized
        )
    }
}

extension Menu: IChangeMenuItemHandler {
    func changeMenuItem() {
        print("1111")
        // self.currentMenuItem = .addonCreator
    }
}


I want to implement a method so that when a button from the class MenuMainView class is clicked, a method in the extension Menu: IChangeMenuItemHandler is triggered.
extension Menu: IChangeMenuItemHandler {
    func changeMenuItem() {
        print("1111")
        // self.currentMenuItem = .addonCreator
    }
}


I can provide answer to two of your problems.

handlerChangeMenuItemDelegate: self: in class init, you can refer to properties in the class using self. however self as an object is not ready. self is being process to be ready as an object, and it finish processing at the end of the init scope. that's way this code won't work. for example.
init{ self.someProperty = SomeType(x = 0 , q = self)} I can refer to self.someProperty but I can't use self as a full initialized object in q = self. I hope you got the idea.



I want to implement a method so that when a button from the class MenuMainView class is clicked, a method in the extension Menu: IChangeMenuItemHandler is triggered





make showMapsScene as the selector for your intended button. then handlerChangeMenuItemDelegate?.changeMenuItem().  in Menu, make mainMenuView.delegate = self. don't forget to conform to the protocol. and that's it. when button is clicked, it will trigger the selector in MenuMainView which will trigger the delegate which will call the delegate method in your Menu class which you can do any configuration you want.
